Google calendar api testing failed
This is Google Calendar API reference code:
import datetime
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"]


def main():
  """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
  Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
  """
  creds = None
  # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  # time.
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print("Getting the upcoming 10 events")
    events_result = (
        service.events()
        .list(
            calendarId="primary",
            timeMin=now,
            maxResults=10,
            singleEvents=True,
            orderBy="startTime",
        )
        .execute()
    )
    events = events_result.get("items", [])

    if not events:
      print("No upcoming events found.")
      return

    # Prints the start and name of the next 10 events
    for event in events:
      start = event["start"].get("dateTime", event["start"].get("date"))
      print(start, event["summary"])

  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()

And these are error messages:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 26, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from http.client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead' from partially initialized module 'http.client' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jchu0\Documents\GitHub\TW-WWH-bot\calendar.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.auth._default import (
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py", line 28, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport._http_client
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "c:\Users\jchu0\Documents\GitHub\TW-WWH-bot\calendar.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
  File "C:\Users\jchu0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: The requests library is not installed from please install the requests package to use the requests transport.

This is my first time coding Google Calendar API, so I have no idea how to solve it.

Where did you get said code?   It looks like you didnt install the libraries it needs.  Just copying code from some place will generally not work you need to understand the code in order to run it.
